# scroll 1000pixels down the page on element click

Tags: html, scroll, click

I have `div id="menuitem1"` and, when someone clicks on that div, I want the page to scroll `1000px` down the page.

I know this is something that's easy to Google, but for some reason, even after reading articles and trying all sorts of things, I can't figure it out. I'm new to this stuff, so please be understanding of that. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#menuitem1").click(function(){
$(window).scrollTo( {top:'1000px'}, 800 );
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried using the scrollTo plugin. I've edited my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the javascript function you need would look something link this:

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,1000); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
}
```

and for the html button, well, just:

```
<input type="button" onClick="pageScroll()" value="Scroll Page">
```

best of luck

Comment: Thank you. That worked, but I guess I failed to mention that I want it to scroll smoothly and slowly, like using the scrollTo plugin.

Comment: take a look at the .animate() property of jQuery, it will animate all sort of CSS properties as well as scroll positions