# Assign "fadeOut" click function to multiple DIVS

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout

EDIT: A few people answered my question very quickly. It was a painfully obvious mistake that I made that was solved simply by changing #buttonclose to .buttonclose. Thanks for everyone for their timely responses!

I have three divs (#window1, #window2, and #window3) that each have a button (#buttonclose). I'm trying to figure out how to fadeOut each div when you click its respective button.

So far, this is what I have for the function:

```
$('#buttonclose').click(function(){
$('#window1').fadeOut(300);
});
```

This works perfectly for #window 1, but I can't figure out how to get it working for #window2 and #window3.

Hopefully you can help me out. I'd really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: IDs must be unique on each document, so using multiple buttons with same id #buttonclose is not valid. Use class instead! BTW, post your relevant HTML, someone will help you

Comment: if each "window" have a "buttonclose" then "buttonclose" should not be an ID , you cant assign an ID multipe times use a class ".buttonclose" in your html file. and show us the html for a "window"

Comment: And please, accept answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14299932/1414562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an ID should be a unique identifier of an element, so it isn't allowed to have multiple elements that have id `buttonclose`. In your case, you could perhaps make it a class instead.

Then, somewhat depending on the DOM-structure, you could do something like this:

```
$(".buttonclose").on("click", function () {
   $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKYC6/)

*This requires that the element to hide is the immediate parent of the button, so you might need to modify it somewhat to better suite your needs.*

If the elements are more deeply nested, methods like `.closest()` might be helpful to you, to find the proper ancestor to hide.

If the element isn't an ancestor of the button, then you need some other way to associate the button with the element to hide, like using a `data-*` attribute on the button element, and store a value in it, like the ID of the element to close. Then read that value when the button is clicked, and select the proper element that way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming HTML like this:

```
<div id="window1">This is window 1 <span class="closeButton">Close</span> 
</div>
<div id="window1">This is window 2 <span class="closeButton">Close</span>
</div>
<div id="window1">This is window 3<span class="closeButton">Close</span>
</div>
```

You can just access the parent of the button and fade that:

```
$(".closeButton").button().click(function () {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q6sQX/2/